# Dummy not responding application

Tags: windows, windows-xp, shutdown

I am currently determining how a production environment handles hung/not responding applications during Windows shutdown.

For testing that, it would be good to have a dummy application that does nothing but to hang / do not respond.

- My first intention was to open `cmd` and start a `ping -t localhost`, but that gets whisked away without any problem.
- Opening `notepad` and typing something without saving is not helping either, because Windows easily detects that it is actually waiting for a response from me.
- Writing a small Java program consisting of nothing but a `while(true) { /* Nonsense */ }` is only a partial solution because of it clogging the system so that none of the other applications respond in time.

Comment: You won't easily reproduce that state. You might get lucky by forcing a deadlock for file operations. But the likely answer is that they are being terminated after a timeout.

Comment: Then, how can an application be "not responding" anyway?

Comment: Because it doesn't respond to system calls and the like in an expected, acceptable time frame. Usually because something broke, it's busy or doesn't have enough resources. The OS itself can always terminate a process.

Comment: Upgrade from Windows XP to a newer and supported OS... Look up the OS setting to forcefully shutdown when you need to complete such as operation such as [`SHUTDOWN`](https://ss64.com/nt/shutdown.html)`/F /R /T 01`... done, next, and onto the next one... Furthermore, you can run [`TASKKILL`](https://ss64.com/nt/taskkill.html)`/F /IM "app.exe"` to potentially kill processes from memory that you may notice causes problem with the reboot.

Comment: Bowl - Do you put tobacco in your bowl and smoke it or what? Seriously though, what did you end up doing with this?

Comment: I ended up with just disabling the component that hung from time to time. But a final decision has not been made yet. I'll definitively post it here if I find a solution that could be of any use for others.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't really found a official Microsoft document that describes what that state indicates. Most often it's associated with a threaded application where one thread is blocking the interaction with the program itself.

Questions that touch on this are:

- [How do I make a console application appear “Not Responding”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12565993/how-do-i-make-a-console-application-appear-not-responding)
- [Program Not Responding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495875/program-not-responding)

A simple example to recreate it (as one of the questions details it's probably very hard for a console application), is to create a Windows Forms application with a button and on the click of the button a really time consuming action is started (a simple `while(true)` or `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(999999)` would do). At that point the GUI won't be able to respond anymore and the process will stop acting up on messages (from what I can tell).

If you check the task manager it should show up as "Not Responding". But it will still be different from other programs that get marked as "Not Responding" as, at least in my very limited testing, there was never a popup telling you that the process stopped to respond.